# When I'm in the entire Calendar year and I tap on a date it doesn't open

Tags: iphone, calendar

Can anyone please tell me why or what I need to do?  If I go to "Today" on calendars all is well.  It's just when I have the months all on screen and tap a date that it won't open.

Comment: Having the same problem. It's happening in month view, not year view just to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

When you're in year view, tapping a date never brings you into that day. The way it works is, in year view, tapping on a date blows up the month you selected, and from month view you can tap on a date to see the day.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually had a phone replaced because of this problem. It started doing this after downloading ios 9 and syncing my outlook calendar to my iPhone 6 plus. It took me anywhere from 6 to 10 taps on the date to get it to open. I have heard from the Apple engineers and they are supposedly working on a fix for the issue...